# Split on capitalized words not between underscores

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given the following string: ThisIsA_SimpleTest_Case

I want to split on all capitalized words not between underscores and on the first underscore of a string between underscores.

The expected splitted result: This Is A *SimpleTest* Case

I came up with the following none working regex, for the Java regex flavor:

```
(?=_[a-zA-Z]*_|[A-Z])
```

But this ofcourse doesn't work since it's an or and not an and. Also this splits on all capitalized words within underscores which is something I want to ignore.

Comment: It seems you should *match*, say, with something like `_[^_]*_|(?<![A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]*`

Comment: _I want to split on all capitalized words not between underscores and on the first underscore of a string between underscores._ confusing!  Can you rephrase it again ?

Comment: Perhaps `(?=(?<!_)[A-Z](?![A-Za-z]*_))|(?<!_[A-Za-z]*|^)(?=[A-Z])|_` https://regex101.com/r/kBekIz/1 then in Java change the infinite quantifier `*` in the lookbehind to `{0,1000}` for example.

Comment: Can there be multiple pairs of underscore ? Or at most one ?

Answer (score 1):

Wiktor is right, it should be easier to try to match instead of splitting on what you don't want.

But because it's a fun challenge, I got one that will split it like you wanted.
`_|(?<!_)(?=[A-Z])(?=[^_]*(?:_[^_]*_[^_]*)*[^_]*$)`

Also works with multiple pairs of underscores.
(It can certainly be improved, I might try to simplify it)

The idea is :

- `_|` Split on any underscore removing it from the final list.
- `(?<!_)` Not right after an underscore. If you don't do that, you might get empty matches after the split (cases already handled by the `_|`). Can be skipped if you don't care.
- `(?=[A-Z])` Split before capital letters.
- `(?=[^_]*(?:_[^_]*_[^_]*)*[^_]*$)` But it must be followed by an even number of underscores. If there are an odd number, it means you're between 2 and it should not split. I assume there can't be an odd number of underscores in the string.

Test at https://regex101.com/r/Iov1Yl/1/

Answer (score 1):

You might split on:

```
(?=(?<!_)[A-Z](?![A-Za-z]*_))|(?<!_[A-Za-z]{0,1000}|^)(?=[A-Z])|_
```

- `(?=(?<!_)[A-Z](?![A-Za-z]*_))` If it is a position where a char A-Z is not directly preceded by `_` and has no `_` at the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<!_[A-Za-z]{0,1000}|^)(?=[A-Z])` If it is a position where what is at the left is not an underscore or the start of the string, and what is directly at the right is a char A-Z
- `|` Or
- `_` Match an underscore

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBekIz/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/2vAXB7)

Example code

```
String regex = "(?=(?<!_)[A-Z](?![A-Za-z]*_))|(?<!_[A-Za-z]{0,1000}|^)(?=[A-Z])|_";
String str = "ThisIsA_SimpleTest_Case";
String[] parts = str.split(regex);

for (String part : parts)
    System.out.println(part);
```

Output

```
This
Is
A
SimpleTest
Case
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach before split:**

The string is changed before split, see context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "ThisIsA_SimpleTest_Case";
    String inputReplace1 =  input.replaceAll("_(\\w+[a-z])([A-Z]\\w+)_", ",$1#$2");
    String inputReplace2 = inputReplace1.replaceAll("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", ",");
    String inputReplace3 = inputReplace2.replaceAll("#", "");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(inputReplace3.split(",")));
}
```

Output:

```
[This, Is, A, SimpleTest, Case]
```